# Facebook PHP SDK v4 login PHP Fatal error Class 'Facebook\\HttpClients\\FacebookCurlHttpClient'

Tags: php, authentication, facebook-php-sdk

Trying to implement facebook login the script will take me to facebook and log me in but when it returns I get a blank page with the url:

[http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/fb.php?code=AQDEaF7gtUklnpQ_EPLLp4TF8zefrL0G2eLUHO02Dyb2zGfKtwpKEeSm_k59z16R71xXqDQKtxkw0FfwVN8Iah-Tx3TzyYBVN2zvarwENCsYcdVT1JmRVvlUXGs8OhbfSHDGPba8M-DVmPJY-lbm8l1mO1CEJ2GTsxrwNhViJdPA6SuiDsp5J1J9sHY0y-1H7Su7rRX4S_QWP3cvPMkTyGJh4EWWYItzW9FjqY0gegSsfQrXjBlwq7fVc9I-4Azic5zqSw-MK5XbYTKbNoKnHZ0j7_5IKOSZtHlNyk8CjJk53_WLyZ0L3Wba-SWB6BU_ubo&state=22579753b75d7714c30f340bb84eb583#*=*](http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/fb.php?code=AQDEaF7gtUklnpQ_EPLLp4TF8zefrL0G2eLUHO02Dyb2zGfKtwpKEeSm_k59z16R71xXqDQKtxkw0FfwVN8Iah-Tx3TzyYBVN2zvarwENCsYcdVT1JmRVvlUXGs8OhbfSHDGPba8M-DVmPJY-lbm8l1mO1CEJ2GTsxrwNhViJdPA6SuiDsp5J1J9sHY0y-1H7Su7rRX4S_QWP3cvPMkTyGJh4EWWYItzW9FjqY0gegSsfQrXjBlwq7fVc9I-4Azic5zqSw-MK5XbYTKbNoKnHZ0j7_5IKOSZtHlNyk8CjJk53_WLyZ0L3Wba-SWB6BU_ubo&state=22579753b75d7714c30f340bb84eb583#_=_)

and the error log shows:
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient' not found in /var/www/html/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php on line 166

I followed the examples and tutorials

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

$id = 'APP_ID';
$secret = 'SECRET_ID';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($id,$secret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/fb.php' );

$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

if (isset($session)) {
    echo "Login Successful";
}
else{
    echo'<a href ="'.$helper->getLoginUrl().'">Login with facebook</a>';
}
?>
```

The fb.php file is on the root and all of the Facebook related files are in a directory under root:

```
fb.php
/Facebook/
/Facebook/Entities/ 
/Facebook/HttpClients/
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you know what version of Facebook SDK 4 you are using? If you are using 4.0.8 you need a few more require statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Facebook SDK 4.0.8, you need a few more require statements to get it running properly:

```
// Facebook PHP SDK v4.0.8
set_include_path("your path to Facebook SDK 4.0.8");

require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
require_once('Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once('Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php');
require_once('Facebook/GraphUser.php');

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
```

You are missing the new `HttpClients` directories in your require statements. Note that this list may have more statements than you originally had, I just copied and pasted the require statements that I utilized in my own application.